# POST input to mail()

Tags: php, email, variables

```
echo '<div id="email">
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <label>E-mailadres:</label>
                <p><input type="text" name="mail1" value="me@me.nl"> </p>
                <input type="submit" name="submitemail"> 
            </form>
    </div>';

    $to = 'MY@MAIL.COM';
    $lala = $_POST['mail1'];

    // subject
    $subject = 'Subject';

    // message
    $message = $selected . $totaal .'';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'From: ' . $lala . ' <' . $lala . '>';

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Sending the email is working fine, it just wont let catch the inserted email.

I can't get the value of `<input .... name="mail1">` (me@me.nl) into the "FROM:" section.

What do i wrong OR what is the thing that i don't do in this case ?

---

Whenever using `$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";` it works perfectly.

Comment: This should work fine. What do the error logs say?

Comment: this code would run all at once. you should add consodering if($_POST['submitemail']){ // code here} and then check what error is showing

Comment: I have tested it and it should have the inputed  value of mail1 in to  $lala

Comment: Use get instead of post and see what comes through in the URL

Comment: a.php/?mail1=me%40me.nl&submitemail=Query+verzenden# is the URL with GET, it sends me the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo '<div id="email">
            <form action="a.php" method="POST">
                <label>E-mailadres:</label>
                <p><input type="text" name="mail1" value="me@me.nl"> </p>
                <input type="submit" name="submitemail"> 
            </form>
    </div>';
if (isset($_POST['submitemail'])) {
    $to = 'MY@MAIL.COM';
    $lala = $_POST['mail1'];

    // subject
    $subject = 'Subject';

    // message
    $message = $selected . $totaal . '';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'From: ' . $lala . ' <' . $lala . '>';

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

the a.php is the name of ur php file

Comment: I'm using `isset($_POST['submitemail']);` top of the whole codes. Whenever i use `$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";` it works perfectly. Else it wont work.